# Как создать ассоциативный массив в C#?

Tags: c#, массивы

Как можно создать ассоциативный массив в c#? В других языках например как js и php это делается легко, но в С# так не работает.

`JS
let i = {"Name" : "Vasa", "Age" : "25"}`

`PHP
$i = ["Name" => "Vasa", "Age" => "25"]`

Comment: словарь что ли?)

Comment: Наверное да....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

Dictionary<string, object> dict = new ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!